# How to interact with async data in render

Tags: reactjs, axios

I sent axios request and received data and I want to interact with this data in render, but due to the fact that the data does not come immediately, it gives me an error when im trying to interact with this data

```
    async componentDidMount() {
            try {
              const commits = await axios.get('url1');
              const members = await axios.get('url2');
        
          const membersNames = await members.data;    //[{},{},{}] structure 
          const commitsData = await commits.data; 
        
              this.setState({
                iteams: {membersNames, commitsData },
              });
            } catch {
              console.log("error");
            }
          }
          render() {
            const { iteams } = this.state;
        
            return (
              <div>
      {console.log(iteams.commitsData[0])} //Cannot read property '0' of undefined
              </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put a null check on 'iteams.commitsData'.

```
<div> 
{
   iteams.commitsData && iteams.commitsData.length > 0 && 
    console.log(iteams.commitsData[0])
} 
</div>
```

Or use Lodash isEmpty function for null check

```
<div> 
   { !isEmpty(iteams.commitsData) && console.log(iteams.commitsData[0])}
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the first solution does not console log anything at all and 2nd is isEmpty is not defined  . I work with class component

Comment: To use isEmpty(), you need to install lodash library.

Comment: is iteams.commitsData[0] is a string or an object ? @reijkee . Please provide a sample for iteams.commitsData